# how to know when an action was performed and close automatically the modal

Tags: wicket

Let's consider the situation where we send, for example, a request and we are waiting a response. 
While we are waiting a modal pops-up with a glyphicon, showing that the request is being processed. The result of this process is going to be an object, when it is null it means that the request was accepted with success, otherwise this object will come with an error message.
I would like to close the modal after receiving the notification, no matter if it was successful or not
can anyone give me an hint of java and wicket?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any piece of code?

Comment: I'm new in this area and I never worked with listeners, I really have to learn them, thanks for the answer, although I changed the code, I put the request to the db inside the modal's class, it solved some of my issues. So I'm not closing the modal automatically, but if I want, I think in my case since the modal is opened after clicking an AjaxLink (this link is in the class that declares the modal) by doing modal.show(target) I only had to do in the end of the code for this link modal.close(target)

Answer (score 1):

Wicket gives you full control over ajax request life-cycle and you can implement your own listener as shown [in the user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_creating_custom_ajax_call_listener)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the modal window after notification recieved, you can make this modal window invinsible, just:

```
public void recieveNotification(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Notification notification = service.getNotification;
    target.add(modalWindow.setVisible(false));
}
```

and you wouldn't see it.